# Generating functions word problem(balloons)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the generating function for the number of ways to create a bunch of n balloons selected from white, gold, and blue balloons so that the bunch contains
at least one white balloon, at least one gold balloon, and at most two blue balloons. How many ways are there to create a bunch of 10 balloons subject to these
requirements?

So I have $$\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2} \cdot \frac{(1-x^3)}{1-x}$$ and I have no idea where to go from here. Have a test on this material in the morning so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by assuming one gold and one white since you're given that as a precondition and then concentrate on the blues in the remaining eight.

Comment: HINT at least two is the same as not zero or one

Comment: HINT HINT find your combinations forumla

Comment: Yeah, that guy is most likely in my class. Looks like he deleted the question. I've looked at that and still have no idea what to do. I know I need to find the coefficient of x^10 but I don't know a general way to accomplish it without counting the ways to get x^10 one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$(x^2-x^5)\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$$

We have the generating function $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+2\choose 2}x^n$$

Multiply by $x^k$ gives $$x^k\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n\ge 0}{n+2\choose 2}x^{n+k}$$

We reindex using $m=n+k$ to get $$x^k\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{m\ge k}{m-k+2\choose 2}x^m$$

We do this twice, for $k=2$ and $k=5$, then subtract.  The result is 
$$(x^2-x^5)\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{m\ge 5}{m-2+2\choose 2}-{m-5+2\choose 2}x^m + \sum_{m=2}^4{m-2+2\choose 2}x^m$$

Hence your answer (for $m\ge 5$) is ${m\choose 2}-{m-3\choose 2}$.  You want $m=10$, so ${10\choose 2}-{7\choose 2}=24$.

Comment: Where did the generating function come from?

Comment: The first line is from the original post. "I have no idea where to go from here."

Comment: Or did you mean the second line?  That's a [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_functions).